# Adding features after classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I would like to add featuers to an existing model, without training it again.

I'm training a model in scikit with partial fitting and would also like to add new upcoming featuers to my existing model. Is there any way to handle this without training the whole model again?.

Imaginary eample, just for clarification (no real data):

[image]

Comment: If your model has never seen category E and you don't want to train your model again, then what is the point of including it in future data? There is no way the old model can use that information.